# IN operator perfomance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there are a chance there will be performance difference if I have something like this in my `WHERE` clause:

```
... Where FieldID IN (35)
```

instead of

```
... Where FieldID = 35
```

Comment: No, the query optimiser treats them as equivalent when it generates the query plan.

Comment: I thought so. Could you please help me to get a proof of this? There is a doubt it can affect the way index is applied to the column then.

Comment: Well, generate the query plan for both, and see if they're the same?

Comment: No difference, the optimizer is smart enough. But in general, [if you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses.](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: The interesting thing is you (and honestly not only you) say "no difference" but suggest to try it on real data and see. So it sounds like everybody doubt a little bit just like me :)

Comment: I have absolutely no doubt, but I know that they're equivalent from practical experience, so I don't have a reference document to point to. 

Honestly, I'd always rather test this sort of thing by looking at the query plans, than by looking at in-depth documentation of the RDBMS's query optimiser!

Answer (score 0):

Read your 'Estimated Execution plan' and 'Actual Execution plan for both.

(In short terms: Race your horses.)

---

You can download Microsoft's 'Adventure Works 2012' demo database for larger examples. Found:

http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/

Comment: Plans look the same for trivial queries. It is hard to analyze real life queries execution plans to see the difference.